# Calculate Surface from vectorfield

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface

I have a vectofield in python, that shows the velocity distribution of particles on an experiment geometry. For each position one has an the velocity in `x` and `y` direction in two arrays `vx` and `vy`

One may do a quiverplot for illustration:[image: quiverplot of vectorfield]

Now I want to calculate the surface that leads to this velocity distribution `z(x,y`). `z` can be rescaled later to apropiate values by a scaling factor.
For the center part it should be a simple linear increase of the `z` for example. For the other parts it should lead to something circular I guess.
I thought about doing cumsums along the x and y axis or so.
But this lead not to the expected results.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Here are some example datas from x=[5,15] and y[0,4]:

```
vy=np.array([
   [ 0.06145939,  0.0570322 ,  0.04584799,  0.01882581,  0.        , 0.        ,  0.        , -0.01882581, -0.04584799, -0.0570322 ],
   [ 0.05489626,  0.04700205,  0.03006774,  0.00924726,  0.        , 0.        ,  0.        , -0.00924726, -0.03006774, -0.04700205],
   [ 0.04715306,  0.03727663,  0.02143105,  0.00589854,  0.        , 0.        ,  0.        , -0.00589854, -0.02143105, -0.03727663],
   [ 0.04019211,  0.03012073,  0.01641931,  0.00433099,  0.        , 0.        ,  0.        , -0.00433099, -0.01641931, -0.03012073]])


vy=np.array([
   [-0.02143105, -0.03006774, -0.04584799, -0.05832448, -0.0665558, -0.0665558 , -0.0665558 , -0.05832448, -0.04584799, -0.03006774],
   [-0.03727663, -0.04700205, -0.0570322 , -0.06378726, -0.0665558 , -0.0665558, -0.0665558 , -0.06378726, -0.0570322 , -0.04700205],
   [-0.04715306, -0.05489626, -0.06145939, -0.0653094 , -0.0665558 , -0.0665558, -0.0665558 , -0.0653094 , -0.06145939, -0.05489626],
   [-0.05314604, -0.05899633, -0.06346224, -0.06585704, -0.0665558 , -0.0665558 , -0.0665558 , -0.06585704, -0.06346224, -0.05899633]])
```

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491517/832621) will give you some insight

Comment: something seems not right with your samples. Shouldn't the rightmost columns of `vx` carry negative values?

Comment: @PaulPanzer , thank you for pointing out. I choosed the wrong subset. Example datas are updated.

Comment: @SaulloCastro . I am sorry, I don't get your idea. How does your link help me? I try to calculate `z`, so to say from the `delta z/delta x` and `delta z/delta y` . In your example `z` is already given ... is my interpretation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive approximation:

```
# calculate midpoints
vxm = 0.5 * (vx[:, 1:] + vx[:, :-1])
vym = 0.5 * (vy[1:, :] + vy[:-1, :])
# integrate
VX, VY = np.zeros_like(vx), np.zeros_like(vy)
VX[:, 1:] = np.cumsum(vxm, axis=-1)
VY[1:, :] = np.cumsum(vym, axis=0)
# compare xy and yx
VYX = VY[:, 0:1] + VX
VXY = VX[0:1, :] + VY
np.nanmax(np.abs(VXY - VYX) / (np.abs(VXY) + np.abs(VYX)))
# 0.12076532205227976     <- not great, but ...
# take mean
E = 0.5 * (VYX+VXY)
E
# array([[ 0.        ,  0.0592458 ,  0.11068589,  0.14302279,  0.1524357 ,
#          0.1524357 ,  0.1524357 ,  0.14302279,  0.11068589,  0.0592458 ],
#        [-0.02935384,  0.02115311,  0.059688  ,  0.08087732,  0.08514562,
#          0.08514562,  0.08514562,  0.08087732,  0.059688  ,  0.02115311],
#        [-0.07156868, -0.02979605,  0.        ,  0.01554169,  0.01796908,
#          0.01796908,  0.01796908,  0.01554169,  0.        , -0.02979605],
#        [-0.12171823, -0.08687318, -0.0628763 , -0.05054064, -0.04899143,
#         -0.04899143, -0.04899143, -0.05054064, -0.0628763 , -0.08687318]])
```

Comment: 0) Thank you very much for your suggestion. (Mod's will beat me for this)
1) You should replace all `1/2` by `0.5` or `1./2.`
2) Why do you use `VX[:, 1:] = np.cumsum(vxm, axis=-1)` instead of `axis=1`
Is there any difference that I do not know?

Comment: @benni `axis=-1`: force of habit, it refers to the last axis, so no difference in 2d. `1/2`: I tend to forget that there are still some older py versions out there.I will update the post. Actually, I'm wondering whether it would make sense to take more integration paths into the average not only the down-down-down-right-right-right and right-right-right-down-down-down ones.

Comment: The point is, that for your solution the integration path is crucial to the result. One could also split up the `VX` cumsum in a right and left side part and connect it by the centered `VY[:,10]` row. This can be of course done automatically for any row in x or y direction.  As all vectors point to the bottom center, I thought it would be better to start a the minimum and then follow the vectors upwards. It would be interesting, if there are other, different ways to calculate the surface.

Comment: @benni I think if we assume that the vector field is the gradient of a surface then all path integrals connecting the same pair of points must agree, The path depndence we see is then a consequence of discretisaton error. So the question is one of finding the best numerics to do the integration. One could try some higher order intregration schemes but I'm not at all an expert on this. But I don't think one can do the reconstruction without performing some integral of some kind.